# Step XMPP prohibits string character U+0040 (@) Jabber .NET

Tags: vb.net, xmpp

I'm trying to connect to a server that has @ in the username and I get that error everytime, any ideas?

```
    With jcSender
        .User = username
        .Password = password
        .NetworkHost = "chat.na1.lol.riotgames.com"
        .Port = 5223
        .SSL = True
        .PlaintextAuth = True
        .Resource = "xiff"
        .AutoReconnect = True
        .AutoRoster = True
        .AutoPresence = True

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using JID

```
Public Function Leaguelogin(ByRef USER As String, ByRef PASSWORD As String)


    Dim account As New jabber.JID(USER + "@pvp.net/xiff")
    Dim j As New JabberClient
    Try         

        j.AutoPresence = True
        j.AutoLogin = True
        j.Server = "pvp.net"
        j.NetworkHost = "chat.na1.lol.riotgames.com"
        j.SSL = True
        j.Port = 5223
        j.PlaintextAuth = True

        j.User = account.User
        j.Password = "AIR_" + PASSWORD
        j.Connect()
        j.Login()
        j.IsAuthenticated = True



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try






End Function
```